# chars like: ' or " in header script code become: &#39; or &quot;

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net-3.5, asp.net-4.0

I recently installed  Visual-Web-Developer 10 and open my old asp.net 3.5 solution in it
and converted it to asp.net 4 solution.
every thing is working fine exept one strange problem:
suddenly all chars like: ' or " in header script code become: `&#39; or &quot;` 
and this making all my javascript do not work and give error in all my solutuin pages.

i tryed to save the page in different encoding but it did not help:
here is example of what happening:
in server side code:

```
HtmlGenericControl Include = new HtmlGenericControl("script");
    Include.Attributes.Add("type", "text/JavaScript");
    Include.InnerText = "browser = \"ie\"; browserVer = '8'; bodyDir = 'rtl'; adverID = '123'; webKind = 'adver';";
    Page.Header.Controls.Add(Include);
    Include.Dispose();
```

on user side i get:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">browser = &quot;ie&quot;; browserVer = &#39;8&#39;; bodyDir = &#39;rtl&#39;; adverID = &#39;123&#39;; webKind = &#39;adver&#39;;</script>
```

big thanks for any halp
chainan

Answer (score 6):

Use the [`InnerHtml`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlcontainercontrol.innerhtml.aspx) property instead, to add the contents of the script. The [`InnerText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlcontainercontrol.innertext.aspx) gets converted..

Quote from `InnerText`

> Unlike the **`InnerHtml`** property, the
>   **`InnerText`** property automatically
>   encodes special characters to and from
>   HTML entities. ...

Comment: You do know the difference between formatting code and quotations, don't you? ;)

Comment: @Marcel, i do :) .. but the initial quote i wanted to post had encoded entities inside it, and the quotation converts them, while the code does not.. kind of like the OP problem ..

Comment: in asp.net 4 you can use litiral control in header section as well

Answer (score 2):

Use [InnerHtml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlcontainercontrol.innerhtml%28VS.71%29.aspx) property instead of InnerText.

*"The **InnerHtml property does not automatically encode special characters** to and from HTML entities. HTML entities allow you to display special characters, such as the < character, that a browser would ordinarily interpret as having special meaning. The < character would be interpreted as the start of a tag and is not displayed on the page. To display the < character, you would need to use the entity `&lt;`.